# How to use TVS diode for Overvoltage Protection while powering Arduino on Vin Pin?

Tags: arduino, diodes, 12v, tvs, polyfuse

I am trying to make a protection circuit for Arduino nano to protecting overvoltage. Normally if I powering "Clone" arduino NANO with 12 Volt, Arduino nano is starting to smoke. So I've learned there is TVS diode for this jop. So I decide to use TVS diode and make this circuit:

[image]

TVs diode starts to smoke when plugged in 12 Volt adaptor for test. If I measure the input voltage of Arduino NANO its about 12 volt so TVS diode does not make its duty.

I am using those PTC fuses

1. [THERMISTOR PTC RESETTABLE FUSE 1206 1.1A 8V](https://ozdisan.com/devre-koruyucular/sigorta-bilesenleri/ptc-sigortalar/KMC3S110RY)
2. [THERMISTOR PTC RESETTABLE FUSE 1206 500mA 8V](https://ozdisan.com/devre-koruyucular/sigorta-bilesenleri/ptc-sigortalar/FSMD050-1206-R)

and those TVS diodes but result is same

1. [DIODE TVS 400W 9V0 DO214AC SMA](https://ozdisan.com/guc-yari-iletkenleri/diyotlar-modul-diyotlar-ve-dogrultucular/tvs-diyotlar/SMAJ9-0A-HT)
2. [DIODE TVS 400W 8V5 DO214AC SMA](https://ozdisan.com/guc-yari-iletkenleri/diyotlar-modul-diyotlar-ve-dogrultucular/tvs-diyotlar/SMAJ8-5A-HT)
3. [DIODE TVS 600W 8.6V DO15 THT](https://ozdisan.com/guc-yari-iletkenleri/diyotlar-modul-diyotlar-ve-dogrultucular/tvs-diyotlar/P6KE10A-TKS)

So can you tell me to how to use this TVS diode?

Comment: If I understand correctly you’re trying to limit the voltage with a tvs? Why not a regulator? The TVS will not work in this application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your schematics are correct but a TVS diode breaks (starts to conduct) when the break-down voltage is reached (in your case 9 V, 8.5 V, 8.6 V), and since there is no resistor between power supply and diode it basically acts like short circuit.

Try adding an 1 kΩ resistor after the fuse, or you can try external voltage regulators like the LM7805 or the AMS1117 5.0.

Side note: TVS diode are best used for sudden voltage spikes, like human-body ESD or lightning. You can use a Zener diode if you want to make a crude voltage regulator.